# how to use a string assigned to a variable as an object key

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

[Using a variable for a key in a JavaScript object literal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2274242/using-a-variable-for-a-key-in-a-javascript-object-literal)

I am started learning javascript and have seen the answer(below) for the above question but

```
var thetop = "top",
obj = { [thetop]: 10 };                                 
console.log(obj.top);
```

what if i have

```
var date = new Date().getDate(); 
var value= String(date); 
obj ={[value]:100};
console.log(obj.value);
```

I did not find the answer for the above code .As the variable value changes everyday i want to use value while using console.log(obj.value) not the actual date.
Can someone tell me how to do it .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can read the value property with "[]" instead of ".", like this:

```js
var date = new Date().getDate(); 
var value= String(date); 
obj ={[value]:100};
console.log(obj[value]);
```